# getLoginurl() returns an invalid URL

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I am a newbie for facebook apps...Just now starting with some basic code got from sites...I created a new app and did everything, but when I use the URL generated by the getLoginurl(), it says "An error occurred. Please try again later." Here is the code which I am using, kindly let me know where I am going wrong..

```
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the website or canvas URL configured in your app settings correct?

If not, because the value returned by getLoginUrl() includes a `redirect_uri` parameter set to the current page's URL, you'll get that error.